# Timeout on socket

Tags: java, sockets, socket-timeout-exception

I have the following method (Coming from this [repo](https://github.com/Soyokaze99/VPNFirewall))

```
private void runVpnConnection() {

    configure();

    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(mInterface.getFileDescriptor());
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(mInterface.getFileDescriptor());

    // Allocate the buffer for a single packet.
    ByteBuffer packet = ByteBuffer.allocate(32767);

    Socket tcpSocket = new Socket();

    boolean ok = true;

    //forwarding packets
    while (ok) {
        // Assume no progress in this iteration.
        try {
            // Read the outgoing packet from the input stream.
            int length = in.read(packet.array());
            if (length > 0) {
                Log.i(TAG, "packet received");
                packet.limit(length);
                String serverIP = "192.168.178.20";//getDestinationIP(packet);
                int port = 5002; //getDestinationPort(packet, getHeaderLength(packet));
                //Log.d(TAG, "destination IP: " + serverIP + " port: " + port);
                InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(serverIP);
                SocketAddress socketadd = new InetSocketAddress(serverAddr, port);
                /*
                tcpSocket.connect(socketadd);
                OutputStream outBuffer = tcpSocket.getOutputStream();
                outBuffer.write(packet.array());
                outBuffer.flush();
                outBuffer.close();
                packet.clear();
                */
                //ok = false;

                ByteBuffer packet2 = packet.duplicate();
                PaketData pdata = parsePacket(packet);
                pdata.printValues();
                //debugPacket(packet2);
                //serverIP = pdata.destAddr//getDestinationIP(packet);
                port = pdata.destPort; //getDestinationPort(packet, getHeaderLength(packet));

                Log.d(TAG, "prot:" + pdata.prot);
                if (pdata.prot == 17) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "udp");
                    //socketadd = new InetSocketAddress(pdata.destAddr, port);
                    DatagramSocket s = new DatagramSocket();

                    byte[] data = new byte[pdata.data.capacity()];
                    pdata.data.get(data);

                    if (shouldBeBlocked(pdata.destAddr)) {
                        sendResult("blocked: " + pdata.destAddr.toString() + ":" + pdata.destPort);
                    } else {
                        sendResult(pdata.destAddr.toString() + ":" + pdata.destPort);
                        if (protect(s)) {
                            DatagramPacket p = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length, pdata.destAddr, port);
                            Log.d("SendOutTest", "try sending");
                            try {
                                s.send(p);
                                Log.d("SendOutTest", "send out!");
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            Log.d("SendOutTest", "message:");

                        } else {
                            Log.d("SendOutTest", "protection of socket failed!");
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (pdata.prot == 6) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "tcp");

                    byte[] data = new byte[pdata.data.capacity()];
                    pdata.data.get(data);

                    try {
                        Socket s = new Socket();
                        s.connect(new InetSocketAddress(pdata.destAddr, pdata.destPort), 10000);

                        if (shouldBeBlocked(pdata.destAddr)) {
                            sendResult("blocked: " + pdata.destAddr.toString() + ":" + pdata.destPort);
                        } else {
                            sendResult(pdata.destAddr.toString() + ":" + pdata.destPort);
                            if (protect(s)) {

                                Log.d(TAG, "try sending");
                                try {
                                    OutputStream outStream = s.getOutputStream();
                                    DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(outStream);

                                    int dataLength = data.length;
                                    dos.writeInt(dataLength);
                                    if (dataLength > 0) {
                                        dos.write(data, 0, dataLength);
                                    }

                                    Log.d(TAG, "send out!");
                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                                Log.d(TAG, "message:");

                            } else {
                                Log.d(TAG, "protection of socket failed!");
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (ConnectException ce) {
                        System.out.println("Connection timed out to: " + pdata.destAddr + ":" + pdata.destPort);
                        ce.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException ioe) {
                        System.out.println("Couldn't get data from: " + pdata.destAddr + ":" + pdata.destPort);
                        ioe.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                if (pdata.prot == 1) Log.d(TAG, "ICMP");


                packet.clear();
            }
            /*
            if (tcpSocket.isConnected()) {
                InputStream inBuffer = tcpSocket.getInputStream();
                byte[] bufferOutput = new byte[32767];
                inBuffer.read(bufferOutput);
                if (bufferOutput.length > 0) {
                    String recPacketString = new String(bufferOutput, 0, bufferOutput.length, "UTF-8");
                    Log.d(TAG, "recPacketString : " + recPacketString);
                    out.write(bufferOutput);
                }
                inBuffer.close();
            }*/
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e(TAG, "exception: " + e.toString());
            ok = false;
        }

    }
}
```

What it should do is intercept the packets, check if it isn't on a black list and the route it to it's original destination.

Propblem is that the socket `s` keeps timing out because it can't connect to the port. What's the problem?

I know it should strip the header of the packet and put it in a new packet to send again but I don't know if it is doing that (I have no experience with networking on this level)

Stacktrace

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to /xx.xxx.xxx.xx (port xxx) after 10000ms
03-22 09:59:26.474  27330-28072/willem.com.vpn W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:159)
03-22 09:59:26.474  27330-28072/willem.com.vpn W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
03-22 09:59:26.474  27330-28072/willem.com.vpn W/System.err﹕ at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
03-22 09:59:26.474  27330-28072/willem.com.vpn W/System.err﹕ at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:460)
03-22 09:59:26.484  27330-28072/willem.com.vpn W/System.err﹕ at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:833)
03-22 09:59:26.484  27330-28072/willem.com.vpn W/System.err﹕ at willem.com.vpn.VPN2.runVpnConnection(VPN2.java:199)
03-22 09:59:26.484  27330-28072/willem.com.vpn W/System.err﹕ at willem.com.vpn.VPN2.run(VPN2.java:93)
03-22 09:59:26.484  27330-28072/willem.com.vpn W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Comment: You need to post the stack trace. Are you sure it happens during `connect(),` as opposed to `read()?`

Comment: @EJP see edit, i'm sure it's on the connect

Comment: Well that just means there was no response from the server. Probably a firewall problem.

Comment: I don't have a firewall installed on my Android device

Comment: Then you're going to have to sniff packets and in general investigate to see why the server isn't responding. Why is the Android device the server? Normally it would be the client.

Comment: We are trying to block certain packets without root acces, that is a requirement.

Comment: I can't see the relevance of that. The server isn't responding. That's what you have to investigate. It's either a firewall or a complete break in the network.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73511/discussion-between-liam-de-haas-and-ejp).